# os.path.join does not yield the contents of the file

Tags: python

```
print "Which category would you like to view? Savory, Dessert, Cake, Soup or Drink?    "
category = raw_input()
for x in os.listdir(category): print x
name = raw_input("Which recipe would wou like to view?   ")
fullname = os.path.join(category, name)
f = open(fullname, "r");
print f
```

I am writing a program that will allow users to view the contents of .txt files saved in specific directories. When I run this code I don't get the contents and instead get a message that says this:
open file 'savory/b.txt', mode 'r' at 0x1004bd140

any ideas. I am new to python so i dont have much of an idea as to what is causing the error but i assume it is due to some missing code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `open` is a file object (not the file contents!) .You need to call a method on your file object to actually read the file:

```
f = open(fullname, "r")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

If it's a big file you may want to iterate over the file line-by-line

```
f = open(fullname, "r")
for line in f:
  print line
f.close()
```

On a side note, here's alternate syntax to you don't have to remember to call the `close` method:

```
with open(fullname, "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    print line
```